Where to find downloaded files via Selenium by Gitlab pipeline runner?
I have a Selenium test automation project with Fitnesse and Java, built in a Windows environment. I am trying to set up a Gitlab CI pipeline to run my tests. I have the Gitlab runner installed on an on-prem Windows virtual machine that I log into with a service account.
There is a test case that clicks on a button on a page, a pdf file is downloaded, and then the test case verifies that the pdf downloaded and opens it to verifies the contents.
The test runs fine on my local machine and Chrome downloads it to my C:\Users\vince\Downloads folder. However, in the pipeline, it fails and reports that the location tried was C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Downloads which is obviously not right.
I have been trying to figure out where the file is downloaded, to no avail. I have tried checking the Downloads folder of the host machine, multiple temp folders in Windows, the gitlab runner folder builds\<token>\<ID>\gitlab\<project>\<projectname> and even tried searching for the file name in File Explorer after it was presumably downloaded during the pipeline run.
What am I missing? Is there some kind of Gitlab runner environment I need to check in?

I have no idea where it was actually downloaded but if you know the name of the file, you can do a search for it on the hard drive.

@JeffC I wish it were that simple! I have done a search for the file name already on the hard drive and was unable to find it. I feel like I am missing a piece of a puzzle here.

What was the error message on fail? You should update your question with the full error message as text, properly formatted. Maybe the failure is that it tried to write to the system32 path but it didn't have write access so it actually wasn't downloaded.

BTW... there are ChromeOptions where you can specify the path where downloads should go. See the "Set download directory" section for details.

You need to provide, some minimal code of your webdriver setup, so we can see what you have configured. @JeffC is correct that ChromeOPtions does provide configuration for you to download to a specific directory

@JeffC Thanks, I ended up getting it working using the ChromeOptions, seen here: https://medium.com/@nadeeraderaniyagala/download-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-in-selenium-6c9dcdcfaad0
I ended up just setting the Downloads folder of the service account as the folder to download to, so all is good now. Cheers!

There are ChromeOptions where you can specify the path where downloads should go. See the "Set download directory" section for details. Sample code is below.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "/directory/path");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

